# Create java class not collectable by GC

Tags: java, class, static, singleton

I want to create a class:
- have only one instance
- be accesible during all lifetime of my app.
- class does not have to be destroyed by Garbage Collector.

Can i achive this by using static, or singleton pattern?

Thanks

Comment: A singleton should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to ensure that a **class** cannot be garbage collected is to ensure that it remains reachable.  You could:

- refer to it in another class that is also reachable,
- load it in the initial classloader (which will always be reachable),
- put an instance of the class into a variable that remains reachable,
- etcetera.

In practice, unless your class is dynamically loaded using a classloader that you created yourself, it is *unlikely* that the class will be unloaded / destroyed by the GC.

---

On the other hand ... if you are really concerned about a singleton **instance** (not a **class**) being garbage collected, the normal implementation of the singleton design pattern takes care of that:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static Integer instance = new Integer(42);

    public static Integer getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The `static` variable is reachable as long as the `MySingleton` class remains reachable ... which is normally for the lifetime of the application run; see above.

A `public static` variable would work too, though it is a bad idea from other perspectives.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an enum singleton

```
class MySingleton implements MyInterface {
     INSTANCE;

     // methods
}
```

Ideally such a singleton should be stateless.  Stateful singletons are difficult/error prone to unit test.

If it is not stateless I suggest using dependency injection instead. i.e. create the object once when you application is loading and pass it to all the instances which need it.